# R script applying roman numeral html color names

Tags: r, for-loop, color-palette

I have an R script that I am working to apply HTML color codes to specific Roman numeral values in the dataset. An example of my code is pasted below. I am having a problem with identifying the roman numerals. I will also include a sample of my data. I want to create a new column with the color codes.

```
white = "#F0F8FF"
aqua = "#00FFFF"
black = "#000000"
blue = "#0000FF"
violet = "#8A2BE2"
green = "#7FFF00"
red = "#DC143C"
dblue = "#191970"
orange = "#FFA500"
yellow = "#FFFF00"
data <- read.csv("protiencs.csv")
Data$Color <-{
for (i in data$MG){
  if (data$MG == II){
    data$Color <- white
  }
}
}
```

Here is my data

```
         PI  MG
1   FC001547  II
2   FC002108 III
3   FC002109 III
4   FC003548  IV
5   FC003609   I
6 FC003654-1  IV
```

My desired output would be

```
PI MG Color
FC001547 II #F0F8FF
FC002108 III #00FFFF
```

Corrected code

```
myDat <- read.csv("protiencs.csv", header = TRUE)
myColors <- list(white = "#F0F8FF"
                 , aqua = "#00FFFF"
                 , black = "#000000"
                 , blue = "#0000FF"
                 , violet = "#8A2BE2"
                 , green = "#7FFF00"
                 , red = "#DC143C"
                 , dblue = "#191970"
                 , orange = "#FFA500"
                 , yellow = "#FFFF00")
myDat$MG <- factor(myDat$MG, levels = c("II", "III", "IV", "I"))
myDat$color <- myColors[myDat$MG]
head(myDat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list. The contents of MG are a factor I am assuming:

```
read.table(text = "PI  MG
1   FC001547  II
2   FC002108 III
3   FC002109 III
4   FC003548  IV
5   FC003609   I
6 FC003654-1  IV", header = TRUE) -> myDat

myColors <- list(white = "#F0F8FF"
     , aqua = "#00FFFF"
     , black = "#000000"
     , blue = "#0000FF"
     , violet = "#8A2BE2"
     , green = "#7FFF00"
     , red = "#DC143C"
     , dblue = "#191970"
     , orange = "#FFA500"
     , yellow = "#FFFF00")

myDat$MG <- factor(myDat$MG, levels = c("II", "III", "IV", "I"))
myDat$color <- myColors[myDat$MG]
> myDat
          PI  MG   color
1   FC001547  II #F0F8FF
2   FC002108 III #00FFFF
3   FC002109 III #00FFFF
4   FC003548  IV #000000
5   FC003609   I #0000FF
6 FC003654-1  IV #000000
```

Comment: I seem to only get a NULL output for the color. I have updated my answer above with your code that I tried. Please let me know if you have any ideas for what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I missed a line of your code. I corrected it and it works now thank you!